# How to pass type of combineReducers. Receiving error: Property '... does not exist on type 'Reducer<CombinedState{}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

I am adding typeScript to my react/redux project. I am unable to load my app because I am receiving the error:

[image]

Here in index.tsx is where I combine my reducers and define type state:

```
import FormHandlerReducer from './FormHandler'
import { combineReducers} from 'redux';
import sideDrawerToggle from './sideDrawer'
import submitAlertReducer from './submitAlert'
import classesReducer from './classes'
import testReducer from './testList'
import studySessionReducer from './studySession'
import testGradeReducer from './testGradeHandler'
import homePageReducer from './homePageHandler'

const allReducers = combineReducers({studySessionReducer, FormHandlerReducer, sideDrawerToggle, submitAlertReducer, classesReducer, testReducer, testGradeReducer, homePageReducer})

export default allReducers
export type State = ReturnType<typeof allReducers>;
```

Here is the file where I am trying to use the state

```
import React from 'react';
import './ShowStudySessions.css'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import State from '../../reducers'

interface ShowStudySession {
  studySessions:{
    classId: number,
    testId: number
  }
}

const ShowStudySession = ({studySessions}: ShowStudySession) => { 
  const classId = studySessions.classId
  const testId = studySessions.testId
  const studySessionList = useSelector((state: typeof State) => state.studySessionReducer[classId][testId].studySessionList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe typo, you should use the `type State = ReturnType<typeof allReducers>;` in `useSelector`

`reducers.ts`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const studySessionReducer = () => {};

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  studySessionReducer,
});

export default allReducers;
export type State = ReturnType<typeof allReducers>;
```

`component.tsx`:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { State } from './reducers';

const ShowStudySession = ({ studySessions }) => {
  const classId = studySessions.classId;
  const testId = studySessions.testId;
  const studySessionList = useSelector((state: State) => state.studySessionReducer[classId][testId].studySessionList);

  return null;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2. You were right. I had a typo in my import of State, and how I associated type State with state.